# MS-Access: Finding records with multiple matching criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm learning on the go and really appreciate any help you can give me. 
I need to calculate a record's first appearance in my 'issue log' table.

Raw data is added to the table once per week. If an issue is resolved by the next run, it will be omitted, but if the issue is still there a new record will be appended into the table.

I need to populate a new column with when issue first appeared. The challenge is that if a record is omitted from the previous run, the counter 'resets'.

[table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XUgn.png) - records are added once per week (can take place on different days), record is a repeat if there is a match between certain fields (in this example "country" and "material") and the column that needs to be populated is the "first appearance" column.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Edit - just to clarify, I'm not looking for a **code**, just an idea on how to tackle this. I was thinking of adding the date for the previous report as an additional column, with a VB counting each consecutive appearance, but it seems like there might be an easier solution. Any ideas are welcome, Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify - this is in MS-Access right?  The screen shot you've provided is data in Excel.  Your Access table is represented by columns A:E?

Comment: Hi Darren, correct this is for MS-Access, the excel is a representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your screenshot is a representation of an Access table (Table1) then you need to **SELECT** the **MIN**inimum date for each **GROUP** of Country & Material fields **FROM** Table1.

Try:

```
SELECT      MIN(dDate) AS First_Appearance,
            Country,
            Material
FROM        Table1
GROUP BY    Country,
            Material
ORDER BY    MIN(dDate)
```

**Edit:**
Based on your example data you should only be showing *Romania*, *Ukraine* and *Israel* with material *C* as these are the only records that appear in the latest week (11/09/2016).

*Israel* only appears once, so that date is its first appearance.
*Romania* appears on the 11th and 28th.  As it didn't appear on the 4th then the 11th is it's first appearance.
*Ukraine* appears on the 11th and 4th, so its first appearance is the 4th.

```
SELECT        T1.dDate
            , T1.Country
            , T1.Material
            , MIN(T2.dDate) AS First_Appearance
FROM        Table1 T1 INNER JOIN Table1 T2 ON 
                T1.Country = T2.Country AND
                T1.Material = T2.Material AND
                (T2.dDate + 7 = T1.dDate or T2.dDate = T1.dDate)
WHERE       T1.dDate = (SELECT MAX(dDate) FROM Table1)
GROUP BY    T1.Country, T1.Material, T1.dDate
ORDER BY    T1.Country, T1.Material
```

If you were to look at the previous week (change your WHERE clause to `WHERE T1.dDate = #09/04/2016#`) you'd get:

*Dubai B* with a first appearance of 28th.
*Romania B* with a first appearance of 4th.
*Spain A* with a first appearance of 28th.
*Ukraine C* with a first appearance of 4th.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give it a go. Yes, the excel is a representation, I can't share the Access table as it contains confidential material.

Comment: Hi Darren, it works, thank you! The only problem still remaining is the "reset" for when an issue meeting the two conditions resurfaces after some time.

Comment: Thought you might have that problem.  Is the fact that a Country / Material didn't appear last week the only way of knowing that it's a new issue?

Comment: Yes, you're correct - unfortunately I have no control over the source data. 
I'm trying to think of an idea where this might work. 
If I add a boolean indicator for solve/not solved, and tell my query to exclude all items returning dates SMALLER than last solved. But again, I am probably over complicating things...

Comment: Thanks again :)  to clarify, you are treating the new data run (current week) as a separate table?

Comment: The query joins the table to itself, so yes in a way it does treat it as a separate table - not just the current week though but the whole table.  There's nothing extra you have to do though.  The query creates a Cartesian product of itself where all records are joined to all records, so with 11 records to start with you'll get 11x11 = 121 records and the join condition & where clause pick out the required records. (use `SELECT * FROM Table1 T1, Table1 T2` to see the actual Cartesian product.)